# Getting the wrong output from arrays

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

const int turns = 2022;

int processing(int array[], int number, int index);

int main()
{
    int numLine[turns]; //actual number line
    //int counter = 0; //turns since last refference??
    int previousNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) //for seven turns
    {
        std::cout << "Seed Number " << i+1 << ": "; //Seed Numer 1,2,3... : 
        std::cin >> numLine[i]; //input number
        std::cout << std::endl; // endline
    }

    for (int i = 7; i < turns; i++) //for the entire length of the turns after 7
    {
        previousNumber = numLine[i - 1];
        numLine[i] = processing(numLine, previousNumber, i-2); //set the current element of numLine to the processed number

        std::cout << numLine[i] << " ";
    }
}

int processing(int array[], int number, int index) //processing seeded with int number
{
    int counter = -1; // number of turns since last referrence

    for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--) //searches down from index to 0
    {
        if (array[i] == number) {
            counter = i; //times since its been said
        } 
    }

    if (counter == -1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return counter;
        //has been seen before so return the count
}

// 13,16,10,12,1,5,8 (seed numbers)
```

This is my code, this is the prompt that I was given to design my program: [http://cis.scc.losrios.edu/~TownJ/dinosaur/memory.html](http://cis.scc.losrios.edu/%7ETownJ/dinosaur/memory.html)

When inputting the seed numbers required for the prompt, the output I receive is 9 (for the 2022nd element of the array, this code outputs all the elements) but when putting that into the website, it is incorrect, as is the number before it. I can't see what I am doing wrong, could someone with more experience tell me what I messed up?

Comment: I have successfully compiled the program in visual studio, when ran, it outputs a bunch of numbers (which is what is intended)

Comment: There are several examples given on the linked page along with the correct answer for each. Does your code provide the correct result for those?

Comment: @Retired Ninja  it does not...

Comment: OK. hacked out example and eliminated my doubts.

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do here, you want to return how many steps you need to go back to find a duplicate, but what you return is the index of the duplicate. `counter` literally needs to count.

Comment: @user4581301 okay so it's something i'm doing wrong in my processing function? I'm mistaking the index number for the value held in it somewhere within the search?

Comment: The index number is the location in the array. You could compute the difference between `index` and the starting location, or you could count with `counter`. Your call, but there's a simple elegance in `if (array[i] == number) { return index - i + 1; }`

Comment: Rather than start trying to find the unknown number you should consider solving one where you're given the answer. Once your code calculates a known value correctly move on the the unknown. The step by step example given is a good way to see if you're on the right track. You can step through your code in the debugger and compare  the result for each step.

Comment: You'll be glad to hear you don't need anyone's help to figure this out, just a tool you already have: your debugger! This is exactly what a debugger is for. It [runs your program, one line at a time, and shows you what's happening](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/), this is something that's every C++ developer must know how to do. With your debugger's help you'll able to quickly find all problems in this and all future programs you write, without having to ask anyone for help. Have you tried using your debugger, already? If not, why not? What did your debugger show you?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you to everyone for your help, the following is my code and commented within is an explanation of such, the list of changes I made was big.

```
#include <iostream>

const int turns = 2022;

int processing(int array[], int number, int index); 

int main()
{
    int numLine[turns]; //actual number line
    int previousNumber;

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) //for seven turns
    {
        std::cout << "Seed Number " << i+1 << ": "; //Seed Numer 1,2,3... : 
        std::cin >> numLine[i]; //input number
        std::cout << std::endl; // endline
    }

    for (int i = 7; i < turns; i++) //for the entire length of the turns after 7
    {
        previousNumber = numLine[i - 1];
        numLine[i] = processing(numLine, previousNumber, i); //set the current element of numLine to the processed number

        std::cout << numLine[i] << " "; //displays current value with space
    }
}

int processing(int array[], int number, int index) //processing seeded with array, previous value 
                                                   //on numLine and index position of the for loop (which mirrors the array element index)
{
    int counter = 0; // 

    for (int i = 0; i < index-1; i++) //loop starting at 0 and moving up to the position we are at in the array
    {
        if (array[i] == number) { //if the array element value at loop iteration i is the same as the previous number, then:
            counter = index - i - 1; //set counter to the index position passed, minus the search loop iteration, minus 1
        } 

    }
    return counter; //return the current value of counter
}

// 13,16,10,12,1,5,8 (seed numbers)
```

Comment: If you're interested, here's an dynamic programming approach that executes in linear time (no searching): https://godbolt.org/z/j8WazzcT5 -- it _does_ assume that the possible seeds must lie in the range [0, turns-1].  It's unclear whether that's guaranteed -- if not then a `unordered_map` can be used instead of `vector`.  Such a change may also be appropriate if using a huge value for the number of turns (e.g. millions).

Comment: Asker had the right idea iterating the list backwards. If you go backwards you can stop as soon as you find the first match. This way you have to keep scanning in case there are more after the first match. [Basically Schlemiel the Painter's Algorithm](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/schlemiel_the_painter%27s_algorithm).

Comment: @paddy That's pretty sweet! I went for brute force, as usual. :) https://godbolt.org/z/e8P8T6dPP

Comment: Yeah works well enough, until you set `turns` to 2022000 ;)